# How to scan in multiple characters at once in C?

Tags: c

Say if I want to ask the user to enter one input or two inputs or three.
For example:

```
int num_1, num_2, num_3;
printf("Enter input" );
```

Now I'm struggling to find how to scan either one, two or three.
If I do this:

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &num_1, &num_2, &num_3);
```

it won't work if the user inputs only one or two inputs.
So how do I do it?

Comment: You could use a loop.

Comment: What are the inputs supposed to be separated by? Spaces? Newlines?

Comment: Use fgets to read a line, then split it.

Comment: How is the program supposed to know when the user has finished entering numbers? Should the program ask the user in advance how many numbers the user will be entering? Or should the user enter exactly one line of input containing several numbers separated by spaces, so that the program knows that the user has finished when it encounters a newline?

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple for loop and an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[3];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &arr[i]) != 1) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please check the return values from `scanf`

Comment: .. And why are you using the heap

Comment: PS: `new` is C++. Question is for C

Comment: @EdHeal Sorry it's out of habit. I fixed it.

Comment: But use braces and check the return value from `scanf`

Comment: No worries - But stdlib.c has EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE. Worth looking into

Comment: I don't think that this will solve OP's problem. It will continue asking for input, until the user enters 3 numbers, or the user enters something that cannot be converted to a number. Unfortunately, OP's question is not very clear and OP has not responded to my request for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a cycle and an array for the inputs, for example:

```
/* array where the inputs will be stored. It has the maximum 
   number of elements (3), assuming you want to use static arrays */
int inputs[3];

int n_inputs, i;
/* ask the user how many values he wants to put */
printf("Number of inputs: \n");
if(scanf("%d", &n_inputs) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "scanf fail!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* ask for the inputs values */
printf("inputs [%d]: \n", n_inputs);
for(i = 0; i < n_inputs; i++) {
    if(scanf("%d", &inputs[i]) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "scanf fail!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

*edited to add scanf basic error handling.

Comment: Please check the return values from `scanf`

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop for multiple input. First take the number of input, then loop through that.

For example:

```
int n, i;
printf("Please enter the input threshold: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

int arr[n];
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("Enter number #%d: ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please check the return values from `scanf`

Answer (score 0):

The following program will read exactly one line of input using [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and read up to `MAX_INPUTS` (defined as `3`) numbers from that line using [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_INPUTS 3
#define MAX_LINESIZE 80

int main( void )
{
    long inputs[MAX_INPUTS];
    int num_inputs;
    char line[MAX_LINESIZE], *p;

    //prompt user for input
    printf( "Please enter up to %d numbers: ", MAX_INPUTS );

    //attempt to read one line of input
    if ( fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin ) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "error reading line\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //verify that entire line was read in
    if ( strchr( line, '\n' ) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "line too long\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //read one number per loop iteration
    for (
        num_inputs = 0, p = line;
        num_inputs < MAX_INPUTS;
        num_inputs++
    )
    {
        char *q;

        errno = 0;

        //attempt to convert next number
        inputs[num_inputs] = strtol( p, &q, 10 );

        //break out of loop if unable to find another number
        if ( p == q )
            break;

        //make p point to end of inputted number
        p = q;

        //make sure that entered number is representable as "long int"
        if ( errno == ERANGE )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "number is out of range\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    //output the inputted data
    printf( "You entered %d inputs. The values are:\n", num_inputs );
    for ( int i = 0; i < num_inputs; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%ld\n", inputs[i] );
    }
}
```

This is what happens when I run this program:

```
Please enter up to 3 numbers: 80 30
You entered 2 inputs. The values are:
80
30
```

Comment: @TobySpeight: Thanks for performing the edit which fixed the undefined behavior in my program. I guess I was lucky (or rather unlucky) that the program behaved exactly as intended, despite the missing variadic function argument, when compiling using gcc without the `-Wall` command-line argument. The program was still always printing the correct number of inputs. This is a good example of how important it is to use that command-line argument.